# R: import identically formatted data, make a column corresponding to the original filename, vertically concatenate?

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I am working with some ocean sensors that were deployed at different depths. Each sensor recorded several parameters (time, temperature, oxygen) at different depths, and each outputted an identically formatted file which I have renamed to `'top.csv', 'mid.csv', bot.csv'` (for top, middle, bottom).

I currently have only three files, but will eventually have more so I want to set this up iteratively. Optimally I would have something set up such that:

1. R will import all csv files from a specified directory
2. It will add a column to each data frame called "depth" with the name of the original file.
3. rbind them into a single data frame.

I am able to do steps 1 and 3 with the two lines below. The first line gets the file names from a specific directory that match the pattern, while the second line uses lapply nested in do.call to read all the files and vertically concatenate.

`files = list.files('./data/', pattern="*.csv")`

`oxygenData= do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(paste('./data/',x)))`

The justification to end up with a single data file is to plot them easier, as such: 
`ggplot(data = oxygenData, aes(x = time, y = oxygen, group = depth, color = depth))+geom_line()`

Also, would dealing with this kind of data be easier with data.table? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by building your own function:

```
myFunc <- function(fileName) {
  # read in file
  temp <- read.csv(paste0("<filePath>/", fileName), as.is=TRUE)
  # assign file name
  temp$fileName <- fileName
  # return data.frame
  temp
}
```

Note that you could generalize `myFunc` by adding a second argument that takes the file path, allowing the directory to be set dynamically. Next, put this into `lapply` to get a list of data.frames:

```
myList <- lapply(fileNameVector, myFunc)
```

Finally, append the files using `do.call` and `rbind`.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, myList)
```